# How to handle exceptions raised by @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions

How to handle exceptions raised by @Transactional annotation. In a case where TransactionSystemException includes a ConstraintViolationException due to not null constraint violation for an entity annotated with @Entity.

I am using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have left thinking about "having a need of exception finally!" here is another way to test and validate the constraints and constraint violations. Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator(); Set> constraintViolations = validator.validateValue(Course.class, "name", null); assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size()); –

Answer (score 2):

This particular exception should be handled by fixing the bug it reveals: the code is trying to create an object with a null property, and this property may not be null. It means that the code forgot to populate this property, or didn't handle the validation of the user-entered data correctly.

Comment: In fact, it is the Test code that tries to set up the attribute as null intentionally. I am posting some code for more understanding below in another comment. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you are business rules are actually working. The db handling code correctly recognises that something is wrong if a NOT NULL value is set to NULL. Had this happened in a production you would likely redirect the user to the same page or whatever and say to them that they must not have nulls

Comment: This is the part of Test Class code, that make a constraint violation.

  
        course = courseService.findById(new Long(5));
  course.setDescription(null);
  
  /*
   * Persist entity 
   */
  courseService.mergeCourse(course);
  
        /*
      * Assertion
      */ 
        assertNotNull("Course Description: must not have been presisted.", courseService.findById(new Long(5)).getDescription()); 


And this is the description attribute, given as in the entity 

 @NotNull
 @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
 private String description;      This assertion fails.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The test code supposes that the NotNull annotation will just forbid the new null value of the property to be persisted, and that the old value will just stay in database. This is partially true: it will forbid the property to become null, but it will do so by throwing a runtime exception. It won't let the merge happen without doing anything. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Yeah Right. This is expected behaviour. But the problem is that no exception is thrown when merge() is called, the whole test method runs successfully, but the transaction fails to commit throwing TransactionSystemException, with nested ConstraintViolationException. As it is in fact due to the same reason. But I want the exception to be thrown when merge is called with a "NULL" for "description".

Comment: See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm. validation constraints are checked by PreInsert- and PreUpdateListeners, i.e. just before an insert or update is made to the database. If you just merge, and don't flush, the constraints won't be validated until the automatic flush, at the end of the transaction. This makes sense, since the merge could be only a part of the business logic, which could be followed by manual settingof the NotNull property.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. You are Right. I think I now need to work on how to manually flush the entity manager when the merge is performed. Or I need to look into the PreXXXXX and PostXXXXX listeners. I think the issue has been nearly resolved. What best do you suggest?

Comment: The problem is not with the code, it's with the test. The test wrongly assumes that an exception should be thrown by the call to merge. Make the test flush to see if it catches the exception, but don't touch at the code.

Comment: In fact the service layer currently does the "flush" functionality. So I can not call anything like courseService.flush() to flush manually. It seems that I would need to make changes to PersistentEntity which can call EntityManager's flush method. Merge method in PersistentEntity is currently something like this.   public void merge(T entity) { 
                entityManager.merge(entity);
                      }

Comment: Although I have not tested this another method yet but it seems to me that now the testing is possible even without calling the mergeXXX() method. Here is how we can validate entities and properties and values http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#d0e590

Comment: Then enclose the service call inside a transaction (using TransactionTemplate), and check that an exception is throws when tre transaction is committed.

Comment: It can do what I want but Paragraph Number 9.7 on http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html is a concern too. My web application is going to be a bigger one. So I think I should try the second method left, rather than programmatic transaction management/demarcations.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about the code of the unit test here. The production code should keep using declarative transactions. The code of this particular test could do (basically) - start a transaction using TransactionTemplate - set the NotNull value to null and safe - end the transaction by returning from the TransactionTemplate - check that an exception has been thrown by the TransactionTemplate call. I still don't know why you want to test this particular constraint, because it seems overkill to me, but that's one way of testing that hibernate constraints work.

Comment: Thanks for Great Help. You are right, it simply kills me that I am not facing this issue with persistXXX() where ConstraintViolationException is thrown straight-away. But no exception is being thrown with mergeXXX(). Anyways, what I need is that a way through which, I can test all the methods of my service layer, which will probably have 50 classes and 300+ methods, and with that accordingly 300+ test methods. Which means Testing every bit! Client wants it... Any better ideas you have about testing?

Comment: I have left thinking about "having a need of exception finally!" here is another way to test and validate the constraints and constraint violations.                                        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Course>> constraintViolations = validator.validateValue(Course.class, "name", null);

assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());